# AutoCompleteTextView textColor not set

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am having some troubles changing the textColor of the AutoCompleteTextView on Android 4+, it is always black no matter what.

My main theme is using @style/Theme.AppCompat as parent so the text on this textview is not gonna be visible and I need to change it to white.

On XML i have the following:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/login_username"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="[Username]"
        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions|textFilter"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
```

/>

No matter what color I put on textColor, it is ALWAYS black!

Comment: you have to look out http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5237#c8 this thread to overcome bug in AutocompleteTextview

Comment: My problem is not with the "suggestions" the colors of those are fine as you can see here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pfhxzl518mle7u3/autocomplete.png